# Whats the best free ER-modelling tool?

Tags: sql-server, models, entity-relationship

whats the best free entity relationship modelling tool?
I have an sql server 2008 database that I want to be modelled out with fields and foreign key contraints and I dont particulary like the one which is built into SQL Management studio.

Answer (score 3):

Toad Data Modeler has a free version.

Comment: Just tried this one. But it is not any option for connection against my SQL Server 2008 instance and have it layout my db diagram. Thats the free feature i'm looking for

Comment: Any other suggestions is appreciated.. ?

Answer (score 2):

Neither free nor expensive; I strongly recommend you to take a look: [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/).

**EDIT**: Check this out: [Data Modelling Tools](http://www.databaseanswers.com/modelling_tools.htm)

Comment: I do not have access to pay for one right now unfortunatly.

Comment: Any other suggestions is appreciated.. ?